# Importing Mongo Collection

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Im trying to import a mongo collection onto an EC2 instance, i have used

```
mongoimport -d test -c foo importfile.json
```

This worked fine on my localhost but on my EC2 instance it says

```
mongoimport -d test_mr -c att_live /var/www/html/app/config/schema/reduced.json couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1] couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1
```

I have no problems connecting to my mongodb on the EC2 server and doing commands manually, it just fails on the import.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked your mongo db is running on the default port expected by the import script? If it isn't you will need to specify --port <port>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it....

mongod wasnt running as a daemon, so i could connect to mongo from shell and do querys, but when i exited or ctrl+C'd it closed the entire host process, so when i ran mongoimport theres was nothing to connect to

Comment: Adding the `--fork` flag to your `mongod` invocation will take care of that...